# UIImageView size is not applied when reused in collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uicollectionviewcell

In my collection view one of my cells has a UIImageView who's UIViewContentMode is UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

The UIImageView has constraints that resize it's frame on orientation change.

Most of the time everything works wonderfully. But every once in a while the UIImage is cropped when rotated. It seems to have something to do with the reuse (dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier) as it only happens after a reuse.

In my prepareForReuse I am setting the constraints as they are in my xib.

I have tried setNeedsDisplay. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if you've done this yet, but I would suggest looking at the section titled `How to set auto layout breakpoint in Xcode debugger` in this post: http://staxmanade.com/2015/06/debugging-ios-autolayout-issues/ If you can "catch" it when it happens, it might help eliminate some variables re: where problem lives.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a very similar issue. A collectionView with the cell defined in a xib. The cell has a view that contains UIImageView, which sets width constraint based on orientation mode. It turned out that - **contentMode** set on the UIImageView was being changed underneath. I would suggest take a look at contentMode and ensure that it is set appropriately ([see reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode)) - either 
either ***ScaleAspectFit*** or ***ScaleAspectFill***